# Stable React Native App Suddenly Showing White Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

An app I have been building for the past month using react native suddenly stopped working and started showing a white screen upon running `react-native run-ios`. Sometimes the emulator shows a yellowBox that says `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection`, but other than that, I cannot see any errors. The issue is happening in both the branch I was working on and the master branch, which was definitely stable at its last commit.

These are the dependencies I have currently:

```
"axios": "^0.17.1",
"base-64": "^0.1.0",
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
"query-string": "^5.0.1",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-dotenv": "^0.1.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-persist": "^5.4.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to overcome this obstacle? Or any tools that would help debug? I really would appreciate any help anyone could provide.

[Screenshot of JS Debugger Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnTVT.png)

Comment: Did you try to check the error logs? JS debugger logs? I suspect, somewhere something went wrong while bundling the app.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar I have attached an image of the JS debugger error I am getting, but it seemed to have come out of nowhere. How can I see the other error logs you mentioned?

Comment: I imagine you're using Mac. To open the developer options click "Command + D", and from there enable remote debugging. Open the console and you'll see the logs there. Update here to see if we can help

Comment: As per the screenshot, it clearly a JS error. Seem like the dependencies aren't handled properly. Check you "Auth" declaration. It is showing undefined.

Comment: @DanielReina Any suggestions how I can find the Auth declaration that the error is pointing to? (It says "exports.default" instead of one of my files). The JS error is surprising me because I am getting it even on a stable master branch of my code that hasn't been changed in a month.

Comment: @DanielReina I believe I figured it out, and I have shared my solution below. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution. The error was happening with the `redux-persist` dependency.

In my Redux reducer, I had this case:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch (action.type) {

    case 'persist/REHYDRATE': {
        if (action.payload.auth) {
            const { access_token, refresh_token, expiration } = action.payload.auth;
            return {
                ...state,
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token,
                expiration: expiration,
            };
        } return state;
    }

    // other cases
}
```

But for some reason, there was no payload to the rehydration (hence the error `Cannot read property "Auth" of undefined`).

I commented out this case, reloaded my simulator using `cmd-R`, and everything seemed to work again! **I'm not entirely sure why this fixed the problem, so if anyone has any thoughts, definitely feel free to share.**

Comment: This is actually not a solution. This here should be the question, and the solution would be the explanation to "for some reason, there was no payload". I think I know what could be causing it, but to be sure I'd need to see your reducer. Is that the very top of the reducer? are you handling a `default` in the `switch` statement?

Comment: @DanielReina Yes, the last reducer case is `default: return state;`. Any thoughts?